# Стоит задача настроить wifi на устройстве без интернета

Tags: debian, wifi, драйвер

Чтобы подключить ноутбук к интернету нужно установить драйвер WiFi адаптера rtl8821ce, сам драйвер скачал на флешку. При попытке установить драйвер с командой "`apt install ./rtl8821ce_all.deb`" просит ещё установить разные пакеты-зависимости которые лежат на этой же флешке. Как правильно подмонтировать флешку в cdrom? Или, может быть, есть какой-то другой способ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146379/discussion-on-question-by-user556165----wifi---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, только так фото в вопросе пишу с телефона

Comment: Хорошо, если я эти пакеты, положу в папку home как и где мне указать к ним путь?